# How to collect information from an input radio [react]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, radio-button

```
 return (
    <C.Container>
        <C.SingleCard>
            <C.Radiocard>
                <h4>One Option</h4>
                <input type="radio" name="topping2" />
            </C.Radiocard
           <C.Radiocard>
                <h4>Two Option</h4>
                <input type="radio" name="topping2" />
            </C.Radiocard
         <C.Button> 
           send
         </C.Button>
    </C.Container>
```

I would like to collect option 1 or option 2 the moment I press the button, through an onClick. How can I do this?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. What are all these components?